# Which layer should i use automapper in?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have been developing a project for a while that is has 5 layer. These are Business, DataAccess,Core,Entities and, API. My question is which layer should i create automapper folder in?

[image]

Comment: AutoMapper operates with DTOs and ViewModels,  so the only point where you can place it is in the application layer, since nothing has dependency on the application layer and the application layer references all others. Application Layer in your case is `WebApi` project

Comment: @Tseng my DTOs in entity layer. So if i want to use fluent API where should i place fluent API, i dont use fluent API in Context class. I have seperated it

Comment: Dtos do not belong into entities. Dtos are for cross boundary, hence the name. And the boundary is the rest api or message queue

Comment: I usually place in Business layer (BLL), BLL implies not only main domain logic, but auxilliary logic, which entity mapping belongs to.

Comment: @Ryan what about Fluent API ?

Comment: @Tseng im following an engineer who is famous in my country places DTOs in Entity Layer but he didnt use automapper and fluent api, so i want to use these too but i dont know where i should place them.

Comment: @Ryan: Not sure what you understand under "auxiliary" logic, but business/domain layer are strictly for business logic. Most other stuff, is part of application layer (input validation, navigation (desktop, mobile or SPA applications mostly though)  or "gluing it together" (controllers) or cross boundary mappings. You can't put AutoMapper in your domain, because it needs knowledge of the mapped types and these types (Dtos and ViewModels) are not part of the domain, because they are your contracts to the outside

Comment: Being famous doesn't qualify one to be good at one's doing, see all that influencers these days. The whole single point of DTOs/ViewModels is to detach your domain models from the outside world, which would allow you to change your domain/model without having to change your API contracts to. If you put them in your domain, you can as well use your domain model as your boundary model, but every change on your model breaks the API for external consumers. Putting it anywhere else makes AutoMapper a dependency of your domain logic

Comment: @Tseng then where should i place DTOs, AutoMapper and Fluent API. Excuse me i am inexperienced in backend so i could not understand you.

Comment: Read my first comment: The Application layer.

Comment: @Tseng, by auxiliary i mean, in particular, validation and entities mapping. These two are so common, which should be done in every project, kinda nitty-gritty things.

Comment: @Samet, it depends on whether your Business assembly is gonna be widely reused (with different mapping settings). If so, place mapping configurations (i.e Automapper Profile classes) in application layer, as were said in first comment. If no, place mapping configurations in Business layer, cause of you kinda specify how initial data model is spread to DTO, that's logic, and i prefer to call it auxiliary. That's from my personal experience.

Comment: Well, input validation (user input) - including validation error report back to the UI -  surely **isn't** business/domain layer concern, but application layer concern. Same for mapping from domain to external apis and services. It also isn't reusable, since DTOs/ViewModels are application specific. Not to be confused with domain logic, which ensures class invariants.

Comment: One of the main advantages of layer architecture is, that if you separate it properly, it will show you issues in your design. If you put your Dtos and mappings in the application layer, you can't _accidentally_ use/reference them in the business layer. If you try to do, you will realize that the type is not know and in an instant you will know: "Wait I tried was just wrong. Let me thing how to **correctly** do that". If it's not in the application layer, you could reference it w/o much thought and not realize it that you have application dependency in your domain/business layer