# How can I pass model to an access data layer/EF Core project from a separate ASP.NET Core Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper, ef-core-3.0

I have a design question; thus, no code samples.

I am trying to create an ASP.NET Core Web API project that would use EF Core to communicate with a database. I read about the Data Access design pattern and realize that I have to place a Web API project into a separate project from a data access project (EF Core).

I would reference a data access project (EF Core) from a Web API project and would pass a model to an EF Core project for that model to be mapped to an entity.

My question is, at what project should I conduct the mapping, at the Web API project or at the data access project/EF Core?

If the mapping needs to be done at the data access layer/EF Core, how can I access/recognize the model at the EF Core project since the EF core cannot reference the Web API (no circular reference).

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Seems your design already indicates the answer to your question. You shouldn't implement the mapping inside the data access layer, as it will create circular dependency. As you have only two layers, you can maintain your mapping in API layer where you will have access to both DTOs and Entities.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67953086/which-layer-should-i-use-automapper-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James,

One or two layers (Class Library) can be added to handle tasks like

**Application Layer**

- Mapping
- Performing Business Logic,
- Conversion of DTO to Model and vice versa,
- Holding Request/Response models.
- ....

**Infrastructure/Core Layer**

- Entities
- Base Entities/Repositories
- Common Helper Classes
- .....

You can refer [N-Tier-Architecture-master](https://github.com/nuyonu/N-Tier-Architecture) or [eShopOnWeb](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb) projects.

[image]